# Email Alerts for WSUS Triggered Updates?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, wsus

Our Windows updates are controlled via WSUS. The reboot times are then controlled through a GPO policy (this is called client-side targeting IIRC).

Is there a a good way to get email alerts about when the reboot is going to happen if there is going to be a reboot? Or Maybe just when the updates will be applied?

Answer (score 1):

WSUS does have options for configuring email notifications for updates synchronization and daily or weekly status reports. There are a number of status reports available (update status, computer status, etc) and I'm not sure exactly which reports are emailed when you enable email notifications but it might fit what you're looking for.